# HP 4101: scan-to-email without Digital Sending software?

Tags: hp, printer

Word on the street (well, forums) is that the HP 4101 can scan-to-email without the expensive Digital Sending Suite/software: I've read that you can just set the SMTP gateway and away you go.

However it doesn't appear to be that simple, at least that I can see from the manual and/or from the settings.  I'm not on-site at the moment and can't recall exact errors, but it doesn't send, and complains about not finding or incorrect digital sending settings, even though I've added the SMTP gateway to the configuration.

I telnet'ed into the SMTP server and sent some test messages, so there's nothing wrong with the mail server's config.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a flaky JetDirect card.